# Removing the last item in a listbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project where I have to textboxes name and age and when you click store data it puts it into a array and when the person is do they click list all(which will appear all items in list box). my problem is that the age limit is 1-100 and when it go below or under. it say error message renter age but that age which was type in there is still stored in there array and thus shown in list box how can I stop that  valid age from getting stored in array and shown in list box. ill put the code below for what I have got so far. Thank you.

```
    Dim Ages As String
    Dim Surnames As String

    Surnames = txtNames.Text
    Ages = txtAge.Text

    If txtNames.Text = "" Then

        MsgBox("Enter Name ")
        txtNames.Focus()
        SystemValueAge = SystemValueAge - 1
        SystemValueName = SystemValueName - 1
        txtNames.Focus()

    ElseIf txtAge.Text = "" Then

        MsgBox("Enter Age")
        SystemValueAge = SystemValueAge - 1
        SystemValueName = SystemValueName - 1
        txtAge.Focus()

    ElseIf Ages < 1 Or Ages > 100 Then

        MsgBox("Please Enter Valid Age")
        SystemValueAge = SystemValueAge - 1
        SystemValueName = SystemValueName - 1
        ListBoxShow.Items.RemoveAt(ListBoxShow.Items.Count - 1)
        txtAge.Focus()

    End If

    Dim List As Integer

    If RBName.Checked = True Then

        ListBoxShow.Items.Clear()
        For List = 1 To SystemValueName

            ListBoxShow.Items.Add(Surname(List))

        Next

    End If

    If RBage.Checked = True Then

        ListBoxShow.Items.Clear()
        For List = 1 To SystemValueAge

            ListBoxShow.Items.Add(Age(List))

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just check that your textbox value is between 1 and 100 before add it: `If 1 < CInt(txtAge.Text) < 100 Then ListBox1.Items.Add(txtAge.Text)`

Comment: @Mederic - How can Ages be < 1 and > 100 at the same time?

Comment: @A Friend My bad read the code as in 1 < Ages < 100

Comment: OP, can you show the code where the value is added to the `ListBox`? You should be preventing it rather than removing it afterwards

Comment: Dim List As Integer

        If RBName.Checked = True Then

            ListBoxShow.Items.Clear()
            For List = 1 To SystemValueName

                ListBoxShow.Items.Add(Surname(List))

            Next

        End If

        If RBage.Checked = True Then

            ListBoxShow.Items.Clear()
            For List = 1 To SystemValueAge

                ListBoxShow.Items.Add(Age(List))

            Next

        End If

    End Sub

Comment: ill add it above